# python - csv input error

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, parsing

I try to import csv file using pandas. The csv was uploaded to dropbox, you can access:

```
import pandas as pd
csv_path = "https://www.dropbox.com/s/hulf1rqntmwepql/training_3.csv?dl=0"
data = pd.read_csv(csv_path, sep=',')
```

and get the following error message:

```
CParserErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-bf00f19b4b83> in <module>()
      1 csv_path = "https://www.dropbox.com/s/hulf1rqntmwepql/training_3.csv?dl=0"
----> 2 data = pd.read_csv(csv_path, sep=',')

pandas/parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader.read (pandas/parser.c:7988)()

pandas/parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_low_memory (pandas/parser.c:8244)()

pandas/parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_rows (pandas/parser.c:8970)()

pandas/parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader._tokenize_rows (pandas/parser.c:8838)()

pandas/parser.pyx in pandas.parser.raise_parser_error (pandas/parser.c:22649)()

CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 4, saw 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DropBox used the `dl=` flag to tell it whether it should auto-trigger download or if it should display a UI prompting a user to download.

Right now you're getting a download prompt, try `https://www.dropbox.com/s/hulf1rqntmwepql/training_3.csv?dl=1` instead.

Comment: Was it trying to create a DF object out of alert box?